# Make array out of all checkboxes that were checked?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a list of people I want to pull from a database. Next to each one, I have a checkbox, here:

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check' value='".$rows4['id']."'>
```

They all have to be the same name for me to be able to check all of them / deselect all of them with javascript:

```
// HTML
<input type='checkbox' onClick='checkAll(document.confirm_form.check)' name='allChecker'>

// JS
function checkAll(field) {
    if (confirm_form.allChecker.checked == true) {
        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            field[i].checked = true ;
        }
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
            field[i].checked = false ;
        }
    }
}
```

So how will I come out with an array of all the ones that were checked? I have this, but it only returns the last one checked!

```
<?php 
if ($_POST['send_confirm']) {
    $check = $_POST['check'];
    echo "the check: $check";
}
?>
```

What would my best bet be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the special syntax `name="check[]"` on all the checkboxes. Then the values appear as an array when you retrieve them using $_POST

Here is a good article I found, [passing-input-arrays-in-php](http://jetlogs.org/2007/07/19/passing-input-arrays-in-php/)

Comment: +1, but don't forget that this is a standard PHP trick that also works on every other kind of input element.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with form elements array.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='check[]' value='".$rows4['id']."'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#formid").find("input:checked").each(function()
 {  
   (this.id).attr('checked',true); 
 });
```

use Jquery method to check and uncheck the checkbox